# How do I make Dolphin of KDE Plasma search for files in Windows partition from dual boot Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: multi-boot, kde, kubuntu, kde-plasma-5, dolphin-file-manager

I have dual booted Kubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10. In windows 10 I have the Windows OS on the C: Drive and Data on D: drive. I intend to share the D: drive as the common data drive between Windows and Kubuntu.

To do that, I want to search the D: drive from the KDE file explorer Dolphin, but that is not happening. I have disabled fast startup in Windows and so I can create new files and access files on the D: drive from Kubuntu, but I can't search those files using Dolphin.

Even on Kubuntu, I have removed the D: drive from the "Do not search here" option under the "Search Settings". But it is still not working.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: You need to explain what's actually happening. With Fast Startup disabled it should be as easy as clicking on it in Dolphin.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, yeah I can access the files by clicking using Dolphin. But for example I have a file named "test.docx" on the D: drive and if I try to search it on Kubuntu using the "Find" search bar available at the top in Dolphin, it doesn't show up. I have tried finding the file using the specifying the "everywhere" option available in Dolphin search bar, but it still return nothing.

Comment: I believe Dolphin searches only within the active partition; the "everywhere" selection is in that context (everywhere on that partition).  Try navigating Dolphin to the partition that's the D: drive (probably via /media or /mnt).  With that as the active location, try searching.

Comment: @fixer1234 Doesn't work, even if I navigate to the D: drive (which is listed under devices, on the left panel of Dolphin) and search, Dolphin doesn't return any search results

Comment: Just a thought to distinguish whether the issue is with Dolphin or an OS or filesystem issue:  Install another file manager or search tool (file manager like nemo or pcmanfm, whatever's available in the repository; search tool like catfish).  If that has the same issue, you'll know that it isn't a dolphin problem.